# why powermail form don't send emails?

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x, powermail

I'm using Typo3 powermail mail forms, after send the form is stored in backend but never send a copy to the recepient or user adress. how can i troubleshoot this issue ?
btw, Test emails from installtool works good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you configure your form that it uses the email address of the visitor who fills in the form as sender address? That's not good practice anymore. Most mail servers check the SPF record and reject mails that don't pass that test.

You can configure the default sender name and address via TypoScript. And check if the SPF Record fits for that sender address.

Comment: Thank you @Peter, i will check this

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a subject? I've been fooled more than once because I didn't set the subject.

There are different ways to do this:

- in the Plugin/CE,
- in TypoScript,
- in the overrides in TypoScript.

The value must not be empty after applying this cascade.

(Applies to sender and receiver settings in the same way)

[image: Plugin configuration]

Comment: Thank you for your comment Julian, yes i have already did, but this is not my case here, Peter say that i have to check the SPF record, i will do this and come back if this is works.