# TYPOP3 powermail: why email to receivers is not send?

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x, powermail

I have a TYPO3 website v10 and using powermail forms.
The test mail in installtool is send good.
The mail to user is send good.
The mail to receivers is not send. This is very strange.

Here is my settings from localconf file:

```
'defaultMailFromAddress' => 'contact@company.gmbh',
'defaultMailFromName' => 'contact@company.gmbh',
'defaultMailReplyToAddress' => 'contact@company.gmbh',
'defaultMailReplyToName' => 'contact@company.gmbh',
'transport' => 'smtp',
'transport_sendmail_command' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i',
'transport_smtp_encrypt' => false,
'transport_smtp_password' => '123456789123456',
'transport_smtp_server' => 'smtp.office365.com',
'transport_smtp_username' => 'admin@company.gmbh',
```

Can you please give me some idea why is the email to receivers never works?

Comment: Still the old problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71071698/why-powermail-form-dont-send-emails

Comment: The problem is that the user email works good, but the receivers email does not work.

Comment: This is nearly always the same problem that can be handled with the comment from the documentation: https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/tree/develop/Documentation/FAQ#how-to-solve-spf-defiance

Comment: Thank you Alex, yes i already tried to overwrite with the typoscript configuration, i still have the problem that i get only the user email confirmation but, not receive the receiver email.

Comment: Did you really paste the example TypoScript into your "Setup"? If so, can you please paste your code here?

Answer (score 1):

Things you should check:

- what is the sender address of the mail which is sent to the receiver? You should avoid to use the email address from the form data as sender address because most mail servers check SPF records nowadays. Better use TypoScript to set a static sender address like info@company.gmbh or no-reply@company.gmbh. To increase comfort for the receiver you could set a reply-to address. See [here](https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/f0ba8a8eab0d62c6393925122e82def1024020b8/Configuration/TypoScript/Main/setup.typoscript#L134) for details how to do that.
- is the subject really set? If it's empty no mail is sent.

To track problems further I suggest to use a local development environment like [DDEV](https://github.com/drud/ddev) which provides [Mailhog](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog) out of the box to intercept all mails which are sent from the webserver. This helps a lot to test mails.

Comment: Yes i have already check the sender and i did change the email adress but they are both belong to Microsoft365. Maybe this is why SPF check didn't pass?

Yes subject is already set.

Comment: The email to the user is working good, The form user have the confirmation email, but the website managers (Receiver emails) don't get any emails.

Answer (score 1):

If your receiver mail is sent as `Bcc:` you might have hit an incompatibility of `symfony/mailer` (which TYPO3 uses from v10+) used with `sendmail -i -t` ([symfony/mailer issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/39744)).

You can work around it by using `transport_sendmail_command` = `/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs`.

This [TYPO3 issue](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/92354) explains it, too.